# Rails 3.1 Unable to create with has_one :polymorphic model from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :price, :as => :pricable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :price
    attr_accessible :price_attributes, :price
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pricable, :polymorphic => true
    attr_accessible :price, :price_comment
end
```

I'm trying to insert at rails console with:

```
MenuItem.create({"name"=>"Julie's Mac & Cheese","price"=>{"price"=>14}})
```

but am getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Price(#70145189558680) expected, got Hash(#70145158648700)
```

How do I force this into thinking it is a Price? tried using it as symbol

thx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MenuItem.create(:name => "Julie's Mac & Cheese", :price_attributes => {:price => 14})
```

**edit** Sorry for lack of explanation but the answer is pretty simple... you just weren't passing the right parameter. I also cleaned it up a bit.