# Rails 3.1 adding item to has_one polymorphic via console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a follow-up to this question: [Rails 3.1 Unable to create with has_one :polymorphic model from rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720226/rails-3-1-unable-to-create-with-has-one-polymorphic-model-from-rails-console)

I was wondering how to add with the syntax (if possible):

```
mi = MenuItem.new
mi.name = "Julie's Mac & Cheese"
mi.price << Price.new
mi.save
```

I get the following error:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 > mi.price << Price.new
Price Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "prices".* FROM "prices" WHERE "prices"."pricable_id" = 6 AND "prices"."pricable_type" = 'MenuItem' LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.
```

`mi.price_attributes` didn't work either.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the `<<` is expecting `mi.price` to be an Array. Instead, assign: `mi.price = Price.new`.

Comment: do you mean `mi.price` instead of `m.price`?

Comment: Actually I went to the other question and saw that you're using `has_one`, so yes, you'll need to do `mi.price = Price.new`.

Comment: cool. thx working now. the has_one was issue

Answer (score 0):

per bricker above as it relates to has_one:

mi.price = Price.new